# What does the "verify" parameter to java.util.jar.JarFile mean, precisely?

Tags: java, jar, jar-signing

The constructors for the `java.util.jar.JarFile` take a `verify` parameter, whose only documentation seems to be this single phrase in [the JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/jar/JarFile.html#JarFile(java.io.File,%20boolean,%20int)):

> `verify` - whether or not to verify the jar file if it is signed.

This obviously isn't very precise, though. What does the verification process that `JarFile` does entail? Does it only verify the Jar file not to have been tampered with, or does it also, in some unspecified way, verify the signer certificates to be trusted? What happens if verification fails, or if the signature files are malformed? Is verification eager or lazy, &c&c?

I find it generally weird that such a procedure that seems so intimately connected to core Java security is so poorly documented, so I am concerned that this might be considered an "internal" API that I'm not really supposed to use. Is this the case, or have I perhaps just missed the external documentation somewhere, or is it just some weird oversight?

Comment: OTOH, you're looking at documentation that is more than 10 years old. It has been improved in more recent versions: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/jar/JarFile.html

Comment: this might help -[https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/signindex.html](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/signindex.html)

Comment: @Amit.rk3: As far as I can tell, that only describes the `jarsigner` tool, not the `JarFile` class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably worth looking at *up to date* documentation, rather than documentation from **2004**. :-)

In the [up-to-date documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/jar/JarFile.html), it says:

> If the verify flag is on when opening a signed jar file, the content of the file is verified against its signature embedded inside the file. Please note that the verification process does not include validating the signer's certificate. A caller should inspect the return value of `JarEntry.getCodeSigners()` to further determine if the signature can be trusted.

Comment: Haha, right, this is true. I generally try to stay Java 5-compliant, so I still have that version of the JavaDoc bookmarked. However, even that newer documentation still doesn't seem to describe such things as the possible failure modes, unless I'm still being blind.

Comment: @Dolda2000: I would expect that if the constructor is accepting the flag, it will do the verification before allowing the object to be constructed. But yes, it would be nice if it would say one way or another, as either (proactive, or just reactive when you try to read from an entry) would be a reasonable implementation approach. You can, of course, look at the code and find out -- but that tells you what it *does*, not what it's specified to do. At least the updated docs answered the certificate question. :-)